# 3 P-channel MOSFETs in parallel. Massive 12V supply, 10uF capacitor from gate to source. All 3 FETs sometimes fail open simultaneously on power up

Tags: parallel, failure, p-channel

My customer is using three SQD45P03-12_GE3 P-channel MOSFETs in parallel. There is a massive 12 V supply with a  10 uF capacitor from gate to source. There's a single bias resistor. All 3 FETs sometimes fail open simultaneously on power up. Why?

[image]

Comment: Define "massive".

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: Far more info is avaiilable and needed.load vsupply vdrive gate wiring length ... . Duty cycle and periods ...

Comment: Why do you have a 10uF capacitor across the G-S terminals? This will slow down the turn-off time which means the output transistors will dissipate a lot of power during power off transition. Also, when you power up the system, does the control input signal signal start up at zero or briefly high, then zero? What is your load?  What sort of output transistors are you using and are your output transistors mounted on a heat sink? What is your control signal voltage level?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How much capacitance is in the load? Do  you have any way of measuring the peak current? Failure open points to violating the abs max package peak current.

Comment: You need individual gate resistors per MOSFET.

Comment: Little SMD MOSFET sits between "massive" power supply and load with (presumably) "massive" capacitors... Does the power supply have an ENABLE input, preferably with soft-start?

Comment: Why do we need more information to answer properly? MOSFETs could be blown by excess current, power, or voltage. Voltage is less likely IMO because it only occurs during power-on. The 10 uF is suspicious, it seems like a hack to fix a different problem, possibly an output glitch during power-on. I would guess that variations in power source ramp time and/or glitches on the control line during power-on are occasionally putting the MOSFET in the linear region for a longer time. Probe the circuit, run lots of tests.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing a slow 2.2 ms filtered gate logic speed driver among 3 power FETs is never a good idea.

The chance of mismatched thresholds is almost certain that the lowest will carry all the transient load.  If that fails open then next attempts and cascade failures may result.